# Sharepoint 2010 WebPart: Users in Site Members Group can't save property of web part

Tags: sharepoint, properties, web-parts

I've created some custom property for my web part with Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User) attribute. I changing this property in EditorPartClass in ApplyChanges() Method only. The main problem is user with contribute permission for a site can't save this property when editing personalized view of a page. Changing property applies when user click OK button on EditorPart, but after page postback value returns to its previous condition. Users with full control privilleges saves this property without a problem.
If User has an "Add and Customize Page" privilege property saves too.. But than User can modify web part in shared view too.. It's bad...

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly change the `SafeAgainstScript` attribute on the `SafeControl` tags. This is new in 2010 because of the Client OM. you can't ever be sure that the user won't type malicious JS - so make sure you also encode any input your property takes!